# Optimize query when updating

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have the following query that took too much time to be executed. 
How to optimize it?

```
Update  Fact_IU_Lead   
set  
    Fact_IU_Lead.Latitude_Point_Vente =  Adr.Latitude,  
    Fact_IU_Lead.Longitude_Point_Vente = Adr.Longitude
FROM Dim_IU_PointVente 
INNER JOIN
    Data_I_Adresse AS Adr ON Dim_IU_PointVente.Code_Point_Vente = Adr.Code_Point_Vente 
INNER JOIN
   Fact_IU_Lead ON Dim_IU_PointVente.Code_Point_Vente = Fact_IU_Lead.Code_Point_Vente
WHERE 
    Latitude_Point_Vente is null  
    or Longitude_Point_Vente is null and Adr.[Error]=0
```

Comment: Define "too much time".  Without knowing your full schema, table sizes, indexes, etc there is almost no way anyone here can help you.

Comment: Off topic... your where clause has an OR condition and an AND condition. When doing this, you should always use parenthesis to prevent unexpected results. In this case, it probably doesn't make a difference because it would be weird to have a longitude without a latitude. Regardless, your where clause should probably be (latitude is null or longitude is null) and error = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things I would look at on this to help.

1. How many records are on each table? If it's millions, then you may need to cycle through them.
2. Are the columns you're joining on or filtering on indexed on each table? If no, add them in! typically a huge speed difference with less cost.
3. Are the columns you're joining on stored as text instead of geo-spatial? I've had much better performance out of geo-spatial data types in this scenario. Just make sure your SRIDs are the same across tables.
4. Are the columns you're updating indexed, or is the table that's being updated heavy with indexes? Tons of indexes on a large table can be great for looking things up, but kills update/insert speeds.

Take a look at those first.

I've added a bit of slight cleaning to your code in regard to aliases.
Also, take a look at the where clauses. Choose one of them.
When you have mix and's and or's the best thing you can ever do is add parenthesis.
At a minimum, you'll have zero question regarding your thoughts when you wrote it.
At most, you'll know that SQL is executing your logic correctly.

```
Update Fact_IU_Lead   
set  
    Latitude_Point_Vente =  Adr.Latitude --Note the table prefix is removed
    , Longitude_Point_Vente = Adr.Longitude --Note the table prefix is removed
FROM Dim_IU_PointVente  as pv --Added alias
INNER JOIN
    Data_I_Adresse AS adr ON pv.Code_Point_Vente = adr.Code_Point_Vente --carried alias
INNER JOIN
   Fact_IU_Lead as fl ON pv.Code_Point_Vente = fl.Code_Point_Vente --added/carried alias
WHERE 
    (pv.Latitude_Point_Vente is null or pv.Longitude_Point_Vente is null) and adr.[Error] = 0 --carried alias, option one for WHERE change
    pv.Latitude_Point_Vente is null or (pv.Longitude_Point_Vente is null and adr.[Error] = 0) --carried alias, option two for WHERE change
```

Answer (score 0):

Making joins is usually expensive, the best approach in your case will be to place the update into a stored procedure, split your update into selects and use a transaction to keep everything consistent (if needed) instead.

Hope this answer point you in the right direction :)